# Differences between "has_one" and "belongs_to" in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the difference? advantages and disadvantages? It is a bit confuse for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The belongs to is on the table with the foreign key.  For the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
end
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The profiles table needs to have a user_id field to reference the record in the users table.

Knowing which to be belongs_to and which to be has_one is something many people struggle with.  Generally, if the has_one might likely become a has_many, then that's the side which needs to be has_one.

Comment: ok, but... If I have, for example, a new class (Profile_types)... how should be the relation with Profile class? (Imagine that Profile has profileTypes_id)

Comment: Then a Profile belongs_to a ProfileType, (not the least of which because it has a field named profileTypes_id), and a ProfileType has_many Profiles.

Comment: Thanks Marlin for your answer.

Answer (score 6):

You put **belongs_to** in the table with the foreign key and **has_one** in the referenced table when the relation is **1-1**.

You put **belongs_to** in the table with the foreign key and **has_many** in the referenced table when the relation is **1-n**

Comment: Thanks Coorasse for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

You will need both.
You one on the one class, and the other on to the class you want to connect.

e.g.

```
Class User 
  has_one :profile
end

Class Profile
  belongs_to :user
end
```

After setting up the relation properly, the advantage is that you can access them using `user.profile` or `profile.user`.

Comment: ok, but... If I have, for example, a new class (Profile_types)... how should be the relation with Profile class? (Imagine that Profile has profileTypes_id)

Comment: ys, a Profile has_one ProfileType and a ProfileType belongs_to a Profile. Make sure you have a field profile_type_id of type int in your Profile model then...

Comment: No, a Profile belongs_to a ProfileType and a ProfileType has_many Profiles.

Comment: Yes, when I read the second answer, I was confuse. Thanks Frank for your answer.